# asp.net Email address validator

Tags: .net, validation, email

I am using a regular expressionvalidator in my application to validate emails.
It's using `ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"`

This has worked great for a long time but recently there was a report from a customer that could not create a client with the email adress marie-@domain.com, its a little bit weird address but never the less it works in gmail.

I dont quite understand the expression, so could anybody help me adjust the expression so it also accepts emails in that format?

Comment: The definite problem is the "-". I passed it through a regex validator and removing the "-" does make this address pass through as valid.